# How do I make structure SPA and SSR with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, architecture, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'am using Laravel + Nuxt for current project.
Web app has user pages and admin pages.
user pages are working in Laravel + Nuxt SPA but admin pages should works on pure Laravel SSR.
I dont know how to make project structure.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in this package
https://github.com/m2sd/nuxt-laravel
Main point is route web.php
It redirects SPA requests to Nuxt router
Admin dashboard router should be extracted into new file(ex. admin.php)
Correct answer is following to above article.